# Is there a way to disable quotes on items?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

Is there a way to disable the flavour description texts?

I find these highly annoying, quotes from people and books... a waste of space on the screen. I'm trying to read what an item does, not read a novel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, it's in the game code and people have tried finding ways around it but none have succeeded.